# Do both Kamui Sharingans share one dimension?

Tags: naruto

Since Kakashi has the left eye of Obito, and Obito has his right eye intact, after awakening the *Mangekyō Sharingan*, they both gain the ability of *Kamui* in their eyes.

Using *Kamui*, both are able to teleport things to the other dimension, though Obito does it far more easily than Kakashi, initially. My question is, since they are the same pair of eyes, which once belonged to a single person, do they share the same dimension?

Say, Obito captures someone and keeps them in the other dimension, can Kakashi bring them back, as they may share the same other dimension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Kamui's alternate dimension is one and the same for both Kakashi and Obito. This has been seen a number of times during their fight in the 4th Ninja War.

- Kakashi teleported Gedo Mazo's neck using Kamui, only for Obito to promptly bring it back using *his* Kamui
- Kakashi got a clue to Tobi's identity because a kunai he teleported left a scratch on Tobi's mask who had teleported himself at the same time to avoid Naruto's Rasengan.
- Kakashi then teleports Naruto's Rasengan so that it can hit Tobi in the alternate dimension where he just teleported his arm.

However, the first clue to this fact was given much earlier when Tobi came to talk to Naruto. Kakashi tried to use Kamui on him, only for Tobi to remark, "Don't bother with that Kakashi. It won't work on me."

Comment: I am sure there are a few more examples from that battle, but it is too tiring to look for and list them all. The above list should give you a good idea why they are connected.

Comment: IKR, even my answer took me almost an hour to find the episode.:)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are somewhat connected. As you can see in these pages in [Naruto Manga Episode 597](http://www.mangareader.net/naruto/597/12):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then they realized that he is Uchiha Obito when they prove that their eyes (from Kakashi and *The Masked Man* that time) are really connected.

Comment: Actually the answer is still yes. My answer is just one proof. What do you really want other than that?

Comment: This answer certainly doesn't deserve a down vote. Sure, he used 'eyes' instead of 'dimensions', but it is quite clear what he wants to say. Moreoever, "eyes are connected" is only meaningful if it means "their alternate dimension is connected".